# JSON post with magic quotes plus a quote character in the data

Tags: php, json, stringify

I have a PHP script that accepts posts from other servers in JSON format.  Sometimes the external server has magic quotes enabled, so I pass it through stripslashes() just to be safe.  However, I run into problems when the data being posted also has a quote character.  This also gets escaped by the remote server and then stripslashes on my server incorrectly strips that as well, breaking the JSON.

For example, I can pass and accept the following JSON easily:

```
stuff = {"items":["item1","item2"],
"urls":["url1","url2"],
"pics":["pic1","pic2"]};
```

However, this will break:

```
stuff = {"items":["item_including_quotes1","item_including_quotes2"],
"urls":["url1","url2"],
"pics":["pic1","pic2"]};
```

I do not have control over the remote array values and they can contain single and double quotes.  I do have control over how they are prepared for sending.  Currently the javascript looks like this:

```
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(stuff));
```

and the PHP looks like this:

```
json_decode(stripslashes(urldecode($_POST["stuff"])));
```

This data is posted with javascript JSON.stringify and encodeuricompnent and processed with PHP json_decode and urldecode.

I considered a regex to remove backslashes only when they appear between brackets [], but this seems kludgy.  Is there a more elegant solution for removing only certain slashes?

Comment: I worked around this by sending the object elements to a function that replaces quotes with &#34; before the stringify call and then decoding html entities in the php script.  Would be interested to see if anyone has a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was passing HTML code inside a string value in a JSON structure, and faced the same problem. 
However, i didn't had to replace the quotes, as JSON.stringify gives me a well formed string.

What i did was implementing a modified function from the one stated here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
?>
```

That way, it just applies stripslashes when magic quotes are enabled, and so far it seems not to break my JSON.